# VBA Shape color change

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to programming with VBA. I am trying to change the color and text inside a shape every time it is clicked on. I cant figure out why the code below is not working. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Sub EndSelection1()

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("EndSelectButton1")

        Select Case .Fill.ForeColor.RGB
        Case vbRed
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "PIN"
        Case vbYellow
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "BOX"
        Case Else
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Press to Select"
        End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overflow!***  Define "not working".  An error?  What else have you tried?  Also, check out "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]" and also [these great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).  We like to see that some effort has been made in finding a solution before asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please includes details about what you've tried so far.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: ...also, I tried your code, and it changes the colour of the shape each time I run the code, so we'll definitely need some more detail about the issue you're having.  Does it work for you when you run the procedure from VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me
maybe you're missing something behind it like, for instance:

- assigning a Macro to the shape

  right click on the shape, click "Assign Macro" menu item then choose the "EndSelection1" one (probably preceeded by some sheet name)
- correctly calling the shape

  since your macro acts on "EndSelectButton1" shape, be sure your shape is named after that same string (select the shape and edit the textbox at the right of the formula bar)